# How do I get changes to propagate to all subrepos in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, subrepos

I have recently switched from Subversion to Mercurial for source control and in doing so have split up one repository into several. I used subrepos to manage the dependencies between repositories. The problem is that pull is not suprepo aware so I have to go into each subrepo and pull changes in order to update a repository. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> pull is not suprepo aware

[hg pull](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#pull) should be subrepo aware, provided it is used with the `-u` (`--update`) option.

The [`hg update`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#update) should, when it [comes to subrepos](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos), take them into account:

> Whenever newer Mercurial versions encounter this `.hgsubstate` file when updating your working directory, they'll attempt to pull the specified subrepos and update them to the appropriate state.
>
> Subrepos may also contain their own subrepos and Mercurial will recurse as necessary.

---

The [OP CoreyD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318698/coreyd) adds:

> That has not worked for me.
> I create two repos `/repo` and `/sub` and I clone sub into repo (`/repo/sub`).
> Then I create an `.hgsub` file in `/repo` with this a line like this `sub = ../sub` and commit it.
> When I make changes to `/sub` and then do an update in `/repo /repo/sub` is unchanged.
> Am I doing something wrong?

That looks about right:
SubRepos or submodules (for Git) are all about referening a **precise configuration** (changeset ref for hg, or commit ref for Git, as explained in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194))

When you change anything *outside* of `/repo`, you don't change the `.hgsubstate` file *within* `/repo` recording the exact configuration (changeset reference).
Hence no change at all.

You could rather do your `/sub` changes directly in `/repo/sub`, commit them, then commit `/repo`.
*Then*, a clone of `/repo` would have the new configuration.

Comment: That has not worked for me. I create two repos /repo and /sub and I clone sub into repo (/repo/sub). Then I create an .hgsub file in /repo with this a line like this sub = ../sub and commit it. When I make changes to /sub and then do an update in /repo /repo/sub is unchanged. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @CoreyD: I just completed my answer to better explain why there were no changes on update. The question I refer to in my edited answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194) is about Git, but is still important to read, because the true purpose of a SubRepo/submodule is described there.